# Always perform finally block except for one exception

Tags: python, exception

I have a `try:finally` block that must execute always (exception or not) unless a specific exception occurs. For the sake of  argument let's say it's a `ValueError`, so I'm asking if I can implement:

```
try:
    stuff()
except Exception as e:
    if type(e) is ValueError: raise
    #do important stuff
    raise

#do important stuff
```

in a more elegant fashion to skip copy-pasting `#importantstuff`. If I ruled Python it would look something like:

```
try:
    stuff()
finally except ValueError:
    #do important stuff
```

Putting `#importantstuff` in a function is not an answer, but not possible is.

Comment: No, there's no way to do that. `finally` is for things that must *always* happen. Why not extract the "important stuff" to a method you can call in both places? What does *"not an answer, but not possible is"*, mean?

Comment: _"try:finally block that must execute always (**exception or not**)"_ - Sounds like you don't want a try except

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need `finally` to skip things in specific conditions, you'll need to use an explicit flag:

```
do_final_stuff = True
try:
    # ...
except ValueError:
    do_final_stuff = False
    raise
finally:
    if do_final_stuff:
        # ...
```

You could also use a context manager here, to clean up afterwards. A context manager is passed the current active exception if there is one:

```
class MyContextManager:
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        if exc_type is not ValueError:
            # do cleanup

with MyContextManager():
    # ...
```